# Plot lines from a polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I have a file with many polylines that I decoded with polyline decode on python. The result was a csv with this format:

[(-23.56632, -46.68435),
  (-23.56629, -46.68428),
  (-23.56589, -46.68346),
(-23.56307, -46.6786),
  (-23.56308, -46.67861)],
 [(-23.54487, -46.66172),
  (-23.54485, -46.66192),
  (-23.54464, -46.66237),
  (-23.54461, -46.66244)], ...]

Now I want to open this in QGIS to see the many routes I have but I don't know how to do this.

I've tried "Add delimeter text" > WKT  but it still shows the same error:

Layer is invalid: layer in file:///C:/Users/... is not a valid layer and can't be add to map

Then I tried to change my lat lon appear like this

[image]

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

but I still receive the same error. What can I do?

Comment: Works for my with QGIS 2.18.2 like here https://anitagraser.com/2010/11/29/qgis-delimited-text-layer-now-supports-wkt/. Tested with this two-liner `id;wkt
1;MULTILINESTRING (( 430340 7002500, 435740 7004820 ), ( 430180 7003880, 434580 7005940 ))`

Comment: Show us a line of the file that fails.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little python script, that converts your list of lines with coordinate touples into an importable wkt format:

```
import csv
from osgeo import ogr

polylines = [[(-23.56632, -46.68435), (-23.56629, -46.68428), (-23.56589, -46.68346), (-23.56307, -46.6786), (-23.56308, -46.67861)], [(-23.54487, -46.66172), (-23.54485, -46.66192), (-23.54464, -46.66237), (-23.54461, -46.66244)]]

with open('poly.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['wkt']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter='',escapechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in polylines:
        linestring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
        for point in line:
            linestring.AddPoint(point[0], point[1])
    writer.writerow({'wkt': linestring.ExportToWkt()})
```

If you want to convert them into multilinestrings please have a look at the [osgeo documentation](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html).

The generated csv file should be importable in qgis as text file.

In this case, following would be the outout of the generated csv file:

```
wkt
LINESTRING  (-23.56632  -46.68435  0,-23.56629  -46.68428  0,-23.56589  -46.68346  0,-23.56307  -46.6786  0,-23.56308  -46.67861  0)
LINESTRING  (-23.54487  -46.66172  0,-23.54485  -46.66192  0,-23.54464  -46.66237  0,-23.54461  -46.66244  0)
```